Feynman propagator for the Dirac equation
In Feynman's book "Quantum mechanics and path integrals (1965)", he proposed a propagator Eq.(2.27) for the Dirac equation, which is given as
$$
K(b,a)=\Sigma_R N(R)(i\epsilon)^R
$$
where $N(R)$ is the number of paths possible with $R$ corners. The only explicit expression I can find is from the link below:
https://www.brannenworks.com/plavchan_feynmancheckerboard.pdf
However it seems to be incorrect. If I set the time step $\epsilon$ to be $0$, I should have the propagator being a delta function of $\delta(x-x')$ while the propagator vanishes as we can see from Eq.(2.27).
Is it wrong?
